# html2canvas crashes in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, stack-overflow, html2canvas

I am using `html2canvas` to convert my charts and download as PDF which is working fine every where except in internet explorer using charts in internet explorer it work fine when there are few charts.
But as soon as data increases `html2canvas` breaks down and send a stack over flow like this AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaa
any ideas ?
OR please suggest any alternate to `html2canvas` 
In addition image is stretch on which stack give up and next one is totally empty image

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers have Data URI caracter limitations, if you are using IE 8, and the memory alocated to that image URI is bigger than 32kb it will cause memory overflow. Read this for more specific info :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#Browser_compatibility